# Customize image in GPPSignInButton in Google Plus in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-plus

I need to customize G+ login button (I need to apply an image), is there anyway to customize it? Documentation says it can be customized it if we use multiple social media integrations.

> https://developers.google.com/+/branding-guidelines#plusone-button

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 6):

You can change the image by changing the signIn button's image property as,

```
self.signInButton.style = kGPPSignInButtonStyleStandard;
[self.signInButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"GooglePlus_CustomImage.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal]; //  custom image
```

Hope this may help you..